# Disconnect form input from submitted data after submission in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

I have made a todo app in vue js.It works fine except the data which is submitted and displayed in the div is changeable even after submitting the form.I want the form to save the data permanently in that div.I have managed to display the data in the divs based on form selection.But it is not permanent after submission of the form.For example, The user has submitted the form and the data is displayed in a div, but after submission, the data is changing on input.I have searched for the solution on many sites and forums.But unfortunately, I didn't find one.

I have used vuex for storing form data.

Thank You in Advance.

Here is the code on which I have worked:

```js
ELEMENT.locale(ELEMENT.lang.en)

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    form: {
      name: '',
        desc: '',
        account: '',
        assigned: '',
      status: '',
      priorty:'',
        date: '',
        time: ''
    },
    tasks: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEM(state, payload) {
      // mutate state
      state.tasks.push(payload)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addItem ({ commit },payload) {
      commit('ADD_ITEM', payload)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    todoItems: state => {
      return state.tasks.filter(form => form.status === 'to-do')
    },
    todoItems1: state => {
      return state.tasks.filter(form => form.status === 'in-progress')
    },
    todoItems2: state => {
      return state.tasks.filter(form => form.status === 'done')
    }
  }
})


var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      loading: false,
      form: {
        name: '',
        desc: '',
        account: '',
        assigned: '',
        status: '',
        priorty:'',
        date: '',
        time: ''
      },
      rules: {
          name: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please input Task Name', trigger: 'blur' },
            { min: 3, max: 15, message: 'Length should be 3 to 5', trigger: 'blur' }
          ],
          account: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please input Account Name', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          assigned: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please select Member Name', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          status: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please Enter status', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          priorty: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please select priorty', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          date: [
            { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a Date', trigger: 'change' }
          ],
          time: [
            { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a time', trigger: 'change' }
          ]
        },
      formLabelWidth: '110px',
      timer: null,
    };
    
  },
  store,
  methods: {
      timeformat: function() {
        this.form.date = moment(this.form.date).fromNow();
      },
  
      cancelForm() {
        this.dialog = false
        this.loading = false   
        clearTimeout(this.timer);

      },
      
      submitForm(formName) {
        
        this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
          if (valid) {
             this.$confirm('Do you want to submit?')
        .then(_ => {
          this.loading = true;
          this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            // animation takes time
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert('Form Submitted')
              this.loading = false;
              this.dialog = false;
              this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.form)

            }, 400);
          }, 2000);
        })
        .catch(_ => {
         
        }); 

          } else {
            console.log('error submit!!');
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
     gettodoItems() {
        return this.$store.getters.todoItems
     },
     gettodoItems1() {
        return this.$store.getters.todoItems1
     },
     gettodoItems2() {
        return this.$store.getters.todoItems2
     }
    },
    watch: {
        form: function() {
            console.log(this.form)
        }
        }
}

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
.main{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 15px solid #e7e7e7;
    height: 70vh;

}
.heading{
    background: #c2c8f1;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    row-gap: 5px;
}

.column{
    background: #d7d7d7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.add{
    border: 1px solid #0479cbf7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #0479cbf7;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    background:transparent;
}

.add:hover{
    background: #0479cbf7;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add:target{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tasks{
    display: flex;
}
.tasks h2{
    margin-top: auto;
}
#app{
    margin-left: auto;
}
.el-drawer__header{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.drawer__footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.el-drawer__body>*{
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.el-form-item__content{
    display: grid;
}
.el-form-item__label{
    text-align: start;
}
.drawer{
    width: 45%!important;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.el-form-item{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.el-drawer__close-btn, #el-drawer__title{
    display: none!important;
}
.close{
    float: right;
}
.close:before{
    content: '\00d7';
    cursor: pointer;
}
.el-message-box__btns{
    display: flex;
}
.el-date-editor--date,.el-date-editor--time{
    width: 100%!important;
}
.desc{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
.el-textarea__inner{
    min-height: 100px!important;
}
.card{
    background:white;
    border-left: 3px solid #00ca00;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:  80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#card1{
    border-left: 3px solid #f0667f;
}
.card p:nth-child(1){
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.card p:nth-child(2){
    color:blue;
    font-size: 19px;

}
.card p:nth-child(3){
    color:red;
}

.card p span:before{
    content: '\01F642';
    float:right;
    visibility:hidden;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<head>
<title>--</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="app">
<div class="tasks" style="margin-bottom:auto;">
<h2>My Tasks</h2>
<template>
<el-button class="add" @click="dialog = true">Add Task</el-button>
<el-drawer
  title="Add New Task"
  :visible.sync="dialog"
  :before-close="submitForm"
  direction="rtl"
  custom-class="drawer"
  ref="drawer"
  >
  <div class="el-drawer__header">
  <span role="heading" title="Add New Task">Add New Task</span>
  <div class="close" @click="cancelForm()"></div>
</div>
  <div class="drawer__content">
    <el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form" class="demo-ruleForm">
      <el-form-item label="Task Name" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="name" required>
        <el-input v-model="form.name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="please input"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Description" :label-width="formLabelWidth" class="desc">
      <el-input type="textarea" v-model="form.desc"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Account" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="account" required>
        <el-input v-model="form.account" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type account name for remote search"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Assigned To" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="assigned" required>
        <el-select v-model="form.assigned">
          <el-option label="team1" value="team1"></el-option>
          <el-option label="team2" value="team2"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Status" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="status" required>
        <el-select id="target" v-model="form.status">
          <el-option label="to-do" value="to-do"></el-option>
          <el-option label="in-progress" value="in-progress"></el-option>
          <el-option label="done" value="done"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Priorty" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="priorty" required>
        <el-select v-model="form.priorty">
          <el-option label="high" value="high"></el-option>
          <el-option label="medium" value="medium"></el-option>
          <el-option label="low" value="low"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Due Date" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="date" required>
      <el-date-picker
      v-model="form.date"
      type="date"
      placeholder="Pick a Date"
      format="yyyy/MM/dd">
      </el-date-picker>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Due Time" :label-width="formLabelWidth" prop="time" required>
        <el-time-picker
        v-model="form.time"
        :picker-options="{
        selectableRange: '00:00:00 - 23:59:59'
        }"
        placeholder="Pick a time">
        </el-time-picker>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
    <el-divider></el-divider>
    <div class="drawer__footer">
      <el-button @click="cancelForm()">Cancel</el-button>
      <el-button class="btn" type="primary" @click="submitForm('form')" :loading="loading">{{ loading ? 'Submitting ...' : 'Save' }}</el-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</el-drawer>
</template>
</div>
<section class="main">
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading1">
<h4>To Do</h4>
</div>
<div class="column first">
 <div v-for="item in gettodoItems" class="card" id="card1">
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.name }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.account }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.date }}</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading2">
<h4>In Progress</h4>
</div>
<div class="column second">
 <div v-for="item in gettodoItems1" class="card" id="card2">
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.name }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.account }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.date }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<div class="heading heading3">
<h4>Completed in last 30 days</h4>
</div>
<div class="column third">
 <div v-for="item in gettodoItems2" class="card" id="card3">
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.name }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.account }}</p>
     <p class="form-item">{{ item.date }}</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

</section>
</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/umd/locale/en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.2.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/element/js/form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added vue.js to your snippet, but it is not possible to create a to-do since the submit button is out of view. Please check it and fix accordingly

Comment: Also there's a lot of code, try create a [mcve]

Comment: @T J, The vue.js already exists in my code please scroll down to see it. Also, I didn't understand that how is the button out of view? as it is submitting the form.My question is that make the submitted data unchangeable.Please run the code and submit the form.After submitting, open the form again and change inputs.

Comment: Stack snippet wasn't picking up your scripts. Also there is different sections in it to put HTML, CSS and JS. It doesn't need lot of the boilerplate. Please go into edit mode of the snippet.

Or maybe it's better to create a vuejs codesandbox

Comment: I have edited the code and placed it in different sections.Please check now.Thank You

Comment: Try making a copy of the 'form' model, committing the copy to Vuex, and then clearing the properties of the original 'form' model.  Also, I suggest renaming the 'form' model to something more unique and meaningful, like 'todo'.

Comment: Will try it.Thank You.Can you show me an example of it?I am not getting an idea of how to do it.